# How to list all duplicate lines in multiple python scripts

Tags: python, unix, terminal

I have many python scripts in my project and some of them contain dicts/lists/sets like:

**hi.py**

```
hi_dict = {
    'de': 'hallo',
    'en': 'hello',
}
```

But some files contain similar or even the same dict:

**maintenace/hello.py**

```
class hello(superclass):
    hello_dict = {
        'en': 'hello',
        'fa': 'سلام',
    }
```

I would like to merge same purpose dicts into one (which could be imported from the other occurences). But first I need to find such dicts.

**How can I search all my Python scripts (using Python or Unix terminal commands) for duplicate lines (in this case `'en': 'hello',`), but exclude initial/trailing spaces and blank lines?**

I've found many answers, how to find duplicate lines in already sorted text files, but none of them stated, how to treat unsorted and full-of-blank-lines Python scripts, also none of them said how to exclude initial/trailing spaces.

Note: I use git, so I can damage scripts in order to get the result in any way and then restore them back from last commit easily.

A solution to this could also find duplicate code, which I could merge and reduce code complexity, so definitely this could be applicable also to make better score on codeclimate or to make the whole framework faster.

Comment: You could do a line-by-line diff but that would be inefficient and very, very prone to errors. I wouldn't recommend such processing of any files with a hierarchy where values depend on context. I can hardly think of a scenario where such extreme clean up would increase performance, anyway - after all, Python will reuse memory once it parses and compiles your code so you won't gain anything from it in a production setting anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a simple shell script you can do this:

- strip leading and trailing whitespaces from all the lines
- sort the lines
- compare files using `comm` to get common lines between the files

So you'd do:

```
sed 's/^\s*//;s/\s*$//' first_file.py | sort > sorted_first_file.py
sed 's/^\s*//;s/\s*$//' second_file.py | sort > sorted_second_file.py
comm -12 sorted_first_file.py sorted_second_file.py
```

Now to compare every pair of files in your source tree you could:

- first run the `sed` + `sort` command above and produce `sorted_` versions of those files to reduce the time
- then run a `find` command which, for every filename, runs a `find` command and compares that file to all other files.

Something along the lines of:

```
# remove all leading/trailing spaces
find . -name '*.py' -exec sed -i.no_spaces 's/^\s*//;s/\s*$//' {} \;

# on my machine, for some reason, only when using -i the above sed command
# does not work and I have to split it in two.
#find . -name '*.py' -exec sed -i.no_spaces 's/^\s*//' {} \;
#find . -name '*.py.no_spaces' -exec sed -i 's/\s*$//' {} \;

# sort all files
find . -name '*.py.no_spaces' -exec sort {} -o {}.sorted \;
```

And then the final step is the "double `find`":

```
for filename in $(find . -name '*.py.no_spaces.sorted');
do
    find . -name '*.py.no_spaces.sorted' -not -path "*$filename*" -exec comm -12 "$filename" {} \;
done
```

This should output the common lines between all files.

Note: you probably want to remove empty lines too. You can do this with a `grep` before this final step.

---

NOTE: if you have a relatively large number of files this will take forever to finish. Since the algorithm is O(n^2), so if you have 1000 files it does 1000000 calls to `comm -12`.

Comment: "Note: you probably want to remove empty lines too. You can do this with a grep before this final step." And `sort` doesn't remove empty lines?

Comment: I have got 341 files, but some of them are not .py files, so the number should be lower I would expect 80 000 calls only :)

Answer (score 0):

When the dict part always start with a line ending with `dict = {`, you can select the dict definitions first (perhaps change the search).
In the dict part you are only interested in lines with a `:`, so print those.
Remove the formatting, so remove spaces and tabs (perhaps also the `,`). You can sort (and `uniq -c`) them.

```
sed -n '/dict = {/,/}/ s/:/:/p' inputfiles|tr -d ' \t' | sort
```

Result is something like

```
'de':'hallo',
'en':'hello',
'en':'hello',
'fa':'سلام
```